# Unable to change scroll speed with imwheel in Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I'm trying to increase the scrolling speed using **imwheel**, I've followed the instructions in the 2 sources listed below but I see no change in the speed even after using big multipliers. **imwheel** seems to be working in the sense that I do not get any error messages. Any ideas of what could be going wrong or any alternatives for increasing scrolling speed system wise?

- http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/how-to-change-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html
- http://www.nicknorton.net/?q=node/10#comments

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple restarts and changing the usb port to which I connect the mouse, the scroll speed started being modified by **imwheel**. The issue is fixed.